# Conditional sentence, past condition, future result

Tags: conditional-constructions

I have this sentence to complete:

Anne is not going to the graduation ceremony because she broke her leg last week. 
She (go) ... to the graduation ceremony if she had not broken her leg last week.

I thought that it should be "she would have gone" but it is not correct. 
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "She would go", because it's a future actions. "She would have gone" implies that the graduation ceremony has already taken place, and Anne could not attend it, but "Anne is not going to the graduation ceremony" states that the ceremony will take place in the future.

Comment: _"She would be going..."_ is another valid alternative.

Comment: @SteveES -What is the difference ?